# How do I convert a csv file with one column to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, python-requests

I need some help with a assignment for python. 
The task is to convert a .csv file to a dictionary, and do some changes. The problem is that the .csv file only got 1 column, but 3 rows.

The .csv file looks like this in excel

```
             A                         B

1.male Bob West
2.female Hannah South
3.male Bruce North
```

So everything is in column A.

My code looks so far like this:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("filename.csv"))
d={}
for row in reader:
    d[row[0]]=row[0:]
print(d)
```

And the output

```
{'\ufeffmale Bob West': ['\ufeffmale Bob West'], 'female Hannah South': 
['female Hannah South'], 'male Bruce North': ['male Bruce North']}
```

but I want

```
{1 : Bob West, 2 : Hannah South, 3 : Bruce North}
```

The male/female should be changed with ID, (1,2,3). And i don´t know how to figure out the 1 column thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: split the columns value in Excel into different columns like: [ID, gender, first name, last name] based on '.' and spaces,  and then read the columns in Python?

Comment: If everything is in a single column, it's not really a CSV, it's just a plain text file.

Comment: I am not allowed to do changes in the csv file.

Comment: `\ufeff` should not be in the CSV. I'm poop with encoding issues, though

Comment: You need to parse the text yourself. A regular expression might be useful for this.

Comment: I got no idea where /ufeff come from. It´s not in the .csv file.

Comment: I presume `\ufeff` is in the file, have a look using `hexdump -C filename.csv`

Comment: can you paste the content of your entire csv file?

Comment: It´s just as in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension and enumerate the `csv` object,

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("filename.csv"))

x = {num+1:name[0].split(" ",1)[-1].rstrip() for (num, name) in enumerate(reader)}
print(x)

# output,
{1: 'Bob West', 2: 'Hannah South', 3: 'Bruce North'}
```

Or you can do it without using `csv` module simply by reading the file,

```
with open("filename.csv", 'r') as t:
    next(t) # skip first line
    x = {num+1:name.split(" ",1)[-1].strip() for (num, name) in enumerate(t)}

print(x)

# output,
{1: 'Bob West', 2: 'Hannah South', 3: 'Bruce North'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the given input:

## data.csv:

```
1.male Bob West,
2.female Hannah South,
3.male Bruce North,
```

## Code:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("data.csv"))

d = {}

for row in reader:
  splitted = row[0].split('.')
  # print splitted[0]
  # print ' '.join(splitted[1].split(' ')[1:])
  d[splitted[0]] = ' '.join(splitted[1].split(' ')[1:])

print(d)
```

## Output

```
{'1': 'Bob West', '3': 'Bruce North', '2': 'Hannah South'}
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 11, in <module>
    d[splitted[0]] = ' '.join(splitted[1].split(' ')[1:1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: looks like your data is formatted incorrectly.. this character: `\ufeff`

Comment: Try it in excel. Column A, row 1: male Bob West / row 2: female Hannah South  / row 3: male Bruce North.   Still get the list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

as per Simit, but using regular expressions and realising that your `1.` and `A` and `B` are you just trying to explain Excel cell and column identifiers

```
import re, csv

reader = csv.reader(open("data.csv"))

out = {}
for i, line in enumerate(reader, 1):
    m = re.match(r'^(male|female) (.*)$', line)
    if not m:
        print(f"error processing {repr(line)}")
        continue
    out[i] = m[2]

print(out)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
, line 8, in <module>
    m = re.match(r'^([0-9]+)\.(male|female) (.*)$', line)
NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: `re` is a standard module in Python

Comment: Dont work for me. Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 7, in <module>
    m = re.match(r'^(male|female) (.*)$', line)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 173, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Pandas for stuff like this. You can use Pandas to import it and then export it to a dict.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=-1)
# Creates new columns in the dataframe based on the rules of the question
df['Name']=df[0].str.split(' ',1).str.get(1)
df['ID'] = df[0].str.split('.',1).str.get(0)
```

The dataframe should have three columns:

- 0 - This is the raw data.
- Name - The name as defined in the problem.
- ID - The number that comes before the period.

I didn't include gender, but it really won't fit into the dict. I'm also assuming your data does not have a header.

The next part converts your pandas dataframe to a dict in the output that you want.

```
output_dict = dict()
for i in range(len(df[['ID','Name']])):
    output_dict[df.iloc[i]['ID']] = df.iloc[i]['Name']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import cv with open('Employee_address.txt', mode='r') as CSV_file:
    csv_reader= csv.DirectReader(csv_file)
    life_count=0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count==0:
            print(f'columns names are {",".join()}')
            line += 1
            print(f'\t{row["name"]} works in the {row["department"]} department, and lives in{row["living address"]}.line_count +=1 print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```